# Smoky Sparky Computer of Doom?

Tags: windows-8, power-supply, desktop-computer

Well, I was changing the hard drives in my computer. I disconnected one and rather brusquely plugged a different one in to the same cables. The cables were all tangled so I had to really fenagle with it to get it to fit. Altogether the cabling inside the computer is like an amazon jungle.

But, when I started my computer, all the lights turned off for one second, then there was a semi-bright flash, the computer turned off, and a gentle plume of smoke seemed to waft out from inside the case.

Then for a while, every time I turned it on it would just turn right back off - no spark or smoke.

In a panic, I quickly unplugged and re-connected all the SATA / Power cables to every component. And... the computer started again. Just fine.

Anyone know what happened here?

Comment: It's almost impossible to make a diagnosis; a temporary false contact would be my guess. But almost certainly, your computer needs now a careful and thorough examination for damages (or spark burns at least). Even if everything *appears* to be working, you can't be sure there isn't some other subtle damage that's accumulating.

Comment: The technical explanation for what @lserni described: If the smoke you saw was the magic smoke that gives your computer life, it didn't all escape because the computer still works.  But the loss may have weakened the computer's spirit, in which case, it won't live as long.  If none of it was the magic smoke, it should now be OK.  Unfortunately, it's very difficult to distinguish regular smoke from magic smoke, especially over the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a few certainties, and a few conjectures. I've done some *slightly* inadvisable power tapping from a PC PSU on a running system for bias lighting, and semi intentionally caused the same thing to happen. The symptoms you talk about sound a lot like you somehow getting a short and in this case a spark jumping a gap - which would result in a small spark and 'smoke'. This would trigger the overvoltage protection, which would shut down your PC. By re-doing the connections, the short is fixed and all is good. *My* motherboard actually lets me know overvoltage protection was triggered when this happens but YMMV

I'd check through your power supply cable harness for any crispy or blistered cables or discolored connectors.

Outside that, in most cases your PSU's designed to fail first to protect the rest of your system. If its fine, and there's no obvious issues with the hardware. I'd just let it be/